# Как настроить Contact form 7 на сервере digital ocean?

Tags: wordpress, digitalocean

Знаю что сначала нужно зарегистрировать почту со своим доменом, а потом что нужно ещё сделать?

Comment: Обратиться к сисадмину сервера. ВП ничего не требует

Answer (score 0):

А потом поставить плагин [WP Mail SMTP](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/). Самый простой и надёжный способ.

Comment: А дополнительно на сервере что надо будет делать?

Comment: Нет, не надо...

Comment: При правильно настроенном сервере этот костыль не нужен. Но этот вопрос ни к в ВП ни даже к ДО  отношения не имеет. Это вопросы системного администрирования

Comment: @SeVlad я знаю, что обычно та самая правильная настройка сервера вызывает кучу проблем, особенно с попаданием сервера в чёрные списки. Потому и ответил - проще плагином.

Comment: Как раз правильная не вызывает никаких проблем. :) А то что "слошь и рядом" - это да. (Надеюсь ты выдел в прошлом вопросе скрины в чате)

Comment: @SeVlad видел. Но удивить меня уже сложно, всякого повидал)